# What are the differences between Firefox's Javascript engine and Chrome's V8?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, firefox, jquery

I've noticed that Chrome and Firefox take different amounts of time to render certain things. In general, Chrome has been faster. What should I know about both of them (and IE8/9, too, I guess) when constructing a Javascript/jQuery app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, Spidermonkey (FF) and V8 (Chrome) are very similar in the core javascript engine API in that both try to be standards compliant.  The main difference is that Spidermonkey tends to add some nice extras to their API if they feel it is needed.  All of this is found at the [Mozilla Development Center (MDC) for JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) and well documented if it is not a standard.  On a side note, I personally search the MDC as my primary source for the JavaScript API.

This story is entirely different for IE.  While most of the core API such as `Math` and `String` are the same, IE differs greatly when it comes to the `document` object, and any manipulation therein I would agree with balexandre and say that jQuery does a very good job at taking care of that mess for you.

The last thing that I will mention is while each engine will process the JavaScript code differently (some faster, some slower, etc.), but this can mostly be considered a black box and all you should need to worry about are the differences in the APIs.

Answer (score 1):

If you write a **jQuery app**, you **don't need to worry about anything** as you are developing to a framework/library that does (today) and will continue to do (in future versions) everything under the hood.

if you are **writting plain javascript**, then it's all a **mess** :)

as you need not to develop your app in one browser but to test in all other browsers, and simples things as opening windows and handle ajax calls vary from engine to engine...

so... **please keep aiming to jQuery** :) he will do the hard stuff for you ;)